# BitcoinPHP using JSON-RPC-PHP : how does it works?

Tags: php, wampserver, bitcoin, json-rpc

I am trying to setup http://bitcoinphp.com/ on my wampserver. But in the configuration file "bitcoin.php" there is written :

```
$username="username";
$password="password";
$serveraddress="serveraddress";
$bitcoin = new jsonRPCClient('http://$username:$password@$serveraddress:8332');
```

What should I write for username, password and serveraddress ? 
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is where you would put your `bitcoind` information.

> Bitcoind is a program that implements the Bitcoin protocol for command line and remote procedure call (RPC) use. It is also the first Bitcoin client in the network's history. It is available under the MIT license in 32-bit and 64-bit versions for Windows, GNU/Linux-based OSes, and Mac OS X.